# Pandas: how to drop rows if contains more that 2 entries?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like the following

```
df
        entry
0       (5, 4)
1       (4, 2, 1)
2       (0, 1)
3       (2, 7)
4       (9, 4, 3)
```

I would like to keep only the `entry` that contains two values

```
df
     entry
0    (5, 4)
1    (0, 1)
2    (1, 7)
```

Answer (score 2):

If there are tuples use [`Series.str.len`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.len.html) for lengths and compare by [`Series.le`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.le.html) for `<=` and filter in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df1 = df[df['entry'].str.len().le(2)]
print (df1)
    entry
0  (5, 4)
2  (0, 1)
3  (2, 7)
```

If there are strings compare number of `,` and compare by [`Series.lt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.lt.html) for `<`:

```
df2 = df[df['entry'].str.count(',').lt(2)]
print (df2)
   entry
0  (5,4)
2  (0,1)
3  (2,7)
```